# New to Visual Studio, can't display form

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I don't know how to search this error. I'm new to Visual Studio and as I'm trying the "Hello World" example on Visual Basic, I cannot seems to see the form running. The error is this:

`'WindowsApp1.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.`

`The program '[3492] WindowsApp1.exe' has exited with code -1073741816 (0xc0000008) 'An invalid handle was specified'.`

Then I tried to create new project without any code just a form and when I start, the error still occurred.

I'm sorry if there's already a post about this. Just don't know what to search about this.

Comment: Did you build the program in "Release" mode?

Comment: What do you mean by build? haven't built anything. just a created a Form then click "Start". the left side of "Start" is "Debug" and "Any CPU"

Comment: try reinstalling VS2017, your installation sounds corrupt.

Comment: Aw. Really? Isn't the Administrator Privilege affects this?. I'm using this in the office so I need to inform IT Dept. to reinstall it and I don't want to bother them. But if that's the case then I don't have any choice. Thanks tho.

Comment: When you have a debugger attached, the OS gets a lot more demanding that code properly closes OS handles.  CloseHandle() must always be called with a valid handle, if it is not then it generates an exception to force you to fix the code.  That's important, a handle recycle attack is a nasty and unfixable security problem.  0xC0000008 is the exception code.  This should never happen in a .NET application.  That it does anyway suggests your machine is unstable, possibly infected.  Reformatting the disk is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution for this if anyone encounter this problem. What I did was change the "Any CPU" to x64(in my case) and it seems my problems have been solved.